# Finding orthogonal transformations that map a line into other.

Tags: geometry, isometry

Given two lines in the plane how do I know if there is an orthogonal transformation that maps one into the other?

For example, given two lines $r: (1,2) +
 \big \langle (1,0) \big \rangle
 $ and $s: (1,2) + \big \langle (1,1) \big \rangle$ how do I know if there is any rotation ABOUT THE ORIGIN that maps $r$ into $s$?

I know that a clockwise rotation of $45º$ about the point $(1,2)$ would do it, but I am having trouble if the centre has to be the origin. Any hints?

Comment: what do you mens by $\langle(a,b)\rangle$?

Comment: find the distance of each line from the origin. There is a rotation that works if and only if those distances agree. For example, a line through the origin, rotated about the origin, must be another line through the origin

Comment: @proofromthebook In your case, the first line is of distance $2$ from the origin, whereas the second has distance $1/\sqrt{2}$ from the origin.  Since their distances from the origin are different, there is no linear orthogonal transformation mapping one line to the other.

Comment: @WillJagy I have a vague notion that this should intuitively be true, but I see no obvious proof off the top of my head.  Is there a quick one-liner proof that I'm missing here?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom The between a line and the origin is the length of a segment which is perpendicular to the line (and passes through the origin).  A rotation about the origin will preserve the length of this segment and any two segments of the same length starting at the origin can be mapped onto each other via a rotation.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, similar to what Michael says, there are just two rotations that take a line, not through the origin, to become parallel to another such. One puts them on opposite sides of the origin, one on the same side; they are now parallel and intersect a ray leaving the origin. If they intersect this ray at different points they are not the same line.

Comment: @MichaelBurr thanks!

Comment: @WillJagy thanks!